# LTSpice: Time varying voltage source parameters

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice

I want to design a voltage source on LTSpice, which must have the following parameters .

| Simulation Time | Tr | Tf | Tp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-1m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u |
| 1-2m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u |
| 2-3m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u |
| 3-4m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 98-99m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u |
| 99-100m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u |

Other parameters don't vary.

To make the question clear I am uploading a circuit and its result.

[image: circuit]

Here the source oscillates from 0 to 2ms.
Aim: The source must oscillate on the same pattern from 0 to 100ms.

[image: result1]

Let's zoom in.
Here V2 takes 2.5V while V1 oscillates.
Aim: While V1 oscillates V2 must be off.

[image: result2]

Instead of that we can use just one voltage source and vary parameters through step or func functions. I couldn't find the right way.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an arbitrary waveform using a PWL source. You just specify the time/voltage points that you want the voltage to have.

You might also be able to achieve what you want using the two PULSE sources, each with a switch that is controlled by another pulse. The switches would select which pulse source is active at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

I made a waveform in micro-cap and, I'm sure, LTSpice will have the same facilities: -

[image]

- Sources (V1 and V3) are connected to a common output via switches S1 and S2.
- The switches are controlled by V4 (noting the inversion): -

[image]

- For the first 4 μs one source is connected.
- For the next 4 μs, the second source is connected
- V4 is the controller that selects either source (V3) or source (V2)
- S1 and S2 are the switches I mentioned that select either V3 or V4

If, after so long you want to stop the composite waveform, use another switch and source so that for a certain time period the output above is selected then, after that has run for "a certain time period", it turns the switch off and there will be no more output until the simulation is restarted.

Regarding your input table, are you aware that due to discontinuities in the numbers, you will get a glitch as marked below. Is this what you want: -

| Simulation Time | Tr | Tf | Tp | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-1m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u |  |
| 1-2m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u | **glitch alert** |
| 2-3m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u | **glitch alert** |
| 3-4m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 98-99m | 0.5u | 0.5u | 1u |  |
| 99-100m | 0.495u | 0.495u | 0.99u |  |

Comment: I add that glitch on purpose. Thanks for your answer. I am going to try it and share the result here.

Comment: @elektronik - the glitch - it isn't defined in your table so, realistically, you do ned to do that (not for this Q and A but for proper 100% operation). I didn't bother with it in my simulation of course because I was just showing the method.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, but without the switch: use a voltage source with `Rser=1` and a current source in parallel.